# PHP Xpath help

Tags: php, xml, xpath

Can anyone point me to a good tutorial on xpath or give me a quick lesson here? Also if xpath is for querying xml, what would I need to use to modify the xml? I guess it would need to be something that works hand in hand with xpath?

Cheers,
Franky

Comment: Usually, one could use PHP's XML handling classes to parse and manipulate them element by element (as hinted at by the answers below), or use XSLT to transform an entire XML document. I haven't used it myself, but you may find PHP's XSL extension useful. http://php.net/manual/en/book.xsl.php, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT, http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-xmlphp1.html) is a good overview of working with XML in PHP.

Instead of using XPath, I would recommend using SimpleXML and DOM to parse it. For example...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<books> 
    <book> 
       <title>Great American Novel</title> 
       <characters> 
        <character> 
         <name>Cliff</name> 
         <desc>really great guy</desc> 
        </character> 
    </characters>
  </book>
</books>
```

You could parse by doing this (assuming XML is in `$xmlstr`)...

```
<?php 

  $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr); 

  echo $xml->book[0]->title; // "Great American Novel" 
  ?>
```

Comment: You don't do any xpath in your example.

Comment: That's true, my example uses DOM instead. I edited my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

There's no "quick" introduction to XPath unless you give some example queries. I found the reference/tutorial from [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_intro.asp) to be quite good.

To modify XML documents in PHP you can use [SimpleXML](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) or [XMLReader](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.xmlreader.php)/[XMLWriter](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.xmlwriter.php) (and probably haps of other XML implementations in PECL)